# .htaccess skip rewrite if url equals/contains some words

Tags: .htaccess, stop-words

I have .htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
    php_value session.use_trans_sid 0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

but I want to skip these rules if url contains e.g. **admin**, **administration** words just after domain name (eg. domain.com/admin/ or domain.com/administration/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following conditions before your rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administration/
```

Comment: hmmm...if I want to access domain.com/admin/ i'm redirected to domain.com. Should it be like this? Btw, I want to access domain.com/admin/index.php?aaa=bbb&<...> without any url rewriting.

Comment: The conditions I propose you add state that subsequent rule should not be applied if the url path (after domain.com) starts with /admin/ or /administration/ (regardless of what follows after, e.g. index.php?aaa=bbb). You have to add the conditions before all rules you want to bypass.